How can I track all buy and sell transactions that relate to a specific Token address?
I am new to this and have been trying to figure out how to track buy and sell transactions from any specific token address, such as $WIF(dogwifhat). I want to create something similar to the Transactions table here where the transactions for the token are being displayed real-time(well...almost real time). How can I use the available Solana RPC methods to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What you can do is use the logsSubscribe RPC method to subscribe to log notifications. After that, you can use the getTransaction method to filter the notifications. I did this for tracking a wallet, and the logic should be similar for tracking a token.
To filter transactions when a token is bought or sold, you can look for swap transactions in the getTransaction response. There will be a section that shows the uiAmount, which indicates the amount exchanged. To determine if it's a buy or sell, you can compare the post and pre balances to see if there was a positive or negative change.
Another way to determine if it’s a buy or sell is by filtering swap transactions to see if the swap was from, say, X token to SOL (indicating a sell) or from SOL to X token (indicating a buy).
I hope this helps!

Thanks, I'll look into this and let you know how it went.

This worked as I was hoping. Thanks for the response.

hey, can you share your code
